# Difficulties in aligning ScrollPane in top-left corner

Tags: java, swing, layout

The question is, how do I align `JScrollPane` in resizeble `JPane` so that it aligns to the top-left corner instead of a center?

That feels like obvious task, yet I spent hours trying out all the different layouts and properties.

The frustration can be expressed, as there are only two options I could produce:

1. Use the layout which respects children's maximum preferred size, `FlowLayout` as example. Side effect - `ScrollPane` starts behaving as if it was plain `Panel`:

[image]

2. Use stretchable layout, for instance `BorderLayout` and place the element into `BorderLayout.CENTER` (`BorderLayout.PAGE_START` leads to **1.**). I lose control on the location of Panel, and it in the center:

[image]

When window is small, scroll works as expected though:

[image]

---

Is it possible to have both of the two worlds: have `JScrollPane` not stretch beyound maximum preferred size, yet not lose the **Scroll**?

In case someone needs the source code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class MainPanelTest extends JFrame {


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new MainPanelTest().setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainPanelTest()  {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        setupGUI();
    }

    private void setupGUI() {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
        this.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JComponent filesPanel = setupFilesPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Files", filesPanel);

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Placeholder", secondPanel);

    }

    private JComponent setupFilesPanel() {
        JPanel filesPanel = new JPanel();
        filesPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {
            c.gridy = i;
            filesPanel.add(new JLabel("Test row " + i), c);
        }       

        JScrollPane scrollFilesPane = new JScrollPane(filesPanel);
        scrollFilesPane.setMaximumSize(scrollFilesPane.getPreferredSize());
        return scrollFilesPane;
    }

}
```

Comment: `In case someone needs the source code:` - we can't execute that code. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The problem is not your `JScrollPane` but the `GridBagLayout` which will center its contents if it is not resizable. If you want to understand what’s going on, give every component a visible border.

Comment: @camickr thank you. I modified the code so that it shall be possible to run without making changes.

Comment: @Holger that looks like a step forward. I wrapped the GridBagLayout panel inside of FlowLayout panel, and it seems to give me more control now. Do I understand you right, that the solution will be to have: Frame -> TabbedPane -> ScrollPane -> JPane (Flow or other layout) -> JPane (GridBagLayout)?

Comment: You can solve it with nested panels. Alternatively you can enable cell resizing in the `GridBagLayout` (this does not automatically imply resizing of `Component`s). E.g. set `c.weightx=1;` before the loop and set `c.weighty=1;` for the *last* component should do the trick. This enables resizing of the cells but not of the contained components (as `fill` is still `NONE`) and that’s the situation where the `anchor` comes into play…

Comment: `set c.weightx=1;` because there is only one column this will work  `and set c.weighty=1; for the last component should do the trick.` - since there are multiple rows you need to do it on the last component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridBagLayout` divides the space into logical cells in which the components live. The `anchor` is only relevant if the logical cell is bigger than its component. This may happen if components within the same row/column demand a bigger size or if there is extra space and the associated `weightx` or `weighty` value is not zero. Since your desired behavior is about the extra space, you have to set the weight values accordingly. The `weightx` will be non-zero for the sole column but the `weighty` will be non-zero for the last row only to take up the entire space below it:

```
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
JPanel filesPanel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

c.weightx = 1; // for the column
for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    filesPanel.add(new JLabel("Test row " + i), c);

// now change the last row:
c.weighty = 1;
gridBagLayout.setConstraints(
  filesPanel.getComponent(filesPanel.getComponentCount()-1), c);
```

---

Alternatively you can leave the cells unmodified but manipulate the entire layout by adding an empty extra row and column consuming the additional space which will effectively move the original rows and columns to the upper left corner:

```
// add all visible components which should not grow
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
JPanel filesPanel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    filesPanel.add(new JLabel("Test row " + i), c);

// add an extra row consuming vertical extra space
int nRows=filesPanel.getComponentCount();
gridBagLayout.rowHeights=new int[nRows+1];
gridBagLayout.rowWeights=new double[nRows+1];
gridBagLayout.rowWeights[nRows]=1;
// add an extra column consuming extra horizontal space
gridBagLayout.columnWidths=new int[] { 0, 0 };
gridBagLayout.columnWeights=new double[] { 0, 1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you are trying to achieve:

```java
private JComponent setupFilesPanel() {
    JPanel filesPanel = new JPanel();
    filesPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        c.gridy = i;
        filesPanel.add(new JLabel("Test row " + i), c);
    }       

    // ---- Add this
    JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    newPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    newPanel.add(filesPanel, c);
    // ----

    // ---- change the panel you pass to JScrollPanel constructor:
    JScrollPane scrollFilesPane = new JScrollPane(newPanel); // <--------- newPanel
    scrollFilesPane.setMaximumSize(scrollFilesPane.getPreferredSize());
    return scrollFilesPane;
}
```

The changes are commented.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are valid, but I can Accept only one.